Need help on making a stepper motor run smooth and silent with 3revs/sec (180rpm)
I am trying to make a Nema 23 motor run smooth and as much silent as possible with at least 3 revs/sec. Motor has 2 phases, 4A/phase, 0.9R active resistance and 3.8mH inductance per phase.
I have built myself 2 H-bridges based on L6384E half-bridge driver and AP9987GH mosfets. My power supply is 48V/1.25A. I control the H-bridges with 4 PWM signals from RPi Pico.
I am generating PWM with varying duty cycle in order to emulate a sinewave. If the motor windings are L1 and L2 this is what I am doing.

first  1/2 period --> L1-in = PWM, L1-out = GND
second 1/2 period --> L1-in = GND, L2-out = PWM

The signal on L2-out and L2-in is the same as in L1 but lagging with 90 degrees.
I cannot find out at what frequency is best to run the PWM and at what resultant frequency (depending on pulses in one 1/2 period) to run control the driver so that the motor runs smooth and silent? Currently the motor vibrates very much and if I increase PWM frequency it just starts humming and doesn't rotate.

One thing to consider is the mechanical resonance frequencies (including load, possibly gearing), if any.

currently don't have any load or gearing the motor is just free standing while testing

yes, the goal for now is to make it run smooth and quiet without load. When I understand the principles behind making it without load I will do it with the load later.

The signals on the phase terminals were very noisy when probing them during humming. However I have an oscillogram of it running loud and kind of stuttery here it is (https://imgur.com/a/WDLnf7b)

Do not comment comments asking for clarification or complementary information: edit your post. Things to try: limit scope bandwidth to, say, 20× "PWM frequency", start from the quiet end: sinusoidal phase currents.

(generating PWM with varying duty cycle in order to emulate a sinewave difficult to see in the oscillogram. Can you add at least one trace of phase current lowpass-limited to between 10× step frequency to PWM frequency/10?)

If what you want is smoothness, you should probably be using a L/R drive rather than a current regulation scheme!  600 steps/sec should be easy to achieve with a L/R drive. You want the Back-EMF of the motor to affect the currents so any ringing will be damped out. With current regulators, this does not happen!  Also, a L/R drive avoids torque variations that will occur with PWM. Does your motor have 6 leads? If so, all you need is 4 power MOSFETs and some power resistors. It will also help to reduce the current level in the motor. It is somewhat counterintuitive but try it out...you will see!

If you are driving the motor at 4 amps/phase, and the power supply is rated at 1.25 amps, you clearly have an undersized power supply!

You clearly do not know how ohms law works and what is inductance and impedance! Please explain to me how 48V/1.25A power supply is insufficient to drive 3.6V/4A phase with 3.6mH inductance and 0.9 ohms active resistance?

Step motors usually start from a speed of zero and ramp up to some final velocity. You cannot start at a speed of 600 steps/second if the pull-in torque is insufficient.  This is particularly true if the inertial load is large.  You mention that the motor "starts humming and doesn't rotate".  That sounds a lot like a stall.

I see now that you are not controlling the current with your PWM. You are applying (in effect) a sinusoidal voltage to the phase windings. With the resistance being only the resistance of the motor, this is bound to be unstable even at very low angular velocities. If you add some resistance to both motor phases (in series) that should help. Of course, you will have to step up the voltage to get the current you want. Use of current regulators has the effect of increasing the resistance seen looking out of the motor back into the driver...without using an actual resistor.
